# I am suppose to fetch data (name & email) from api. My program is compiled sucessfully but I'm getting errors in console. https://randomuser.me/api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, http, fetch-api

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);

  useEffect(  ()=> {
    loadData();
    //getData();
  }, []);

  const loadData = async () => {
    await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(receiveddata => setData(receiveddata));
  }

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p> Fetch/ Async/ Await</p>
      {data.map(user => (
        <div key={user.id}>{user.name}, {user.email}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm getting this error on the console,

> Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because `data` is not an Array. The response that you are getting back is an object that has two properties `results` and `info`. Since your state is an array, set the state to `receiveddata.results` instead.

Comment: map on `data.results` will also throw an error because `data` starts as an empty array. So your second option is better (although you could use that if `data` is initialised to an object with a `results` property holding an empty array - the key is keeping your state in the same shape at all times).

Answer (score 0):

Firsteval, your `console.log(data)` will return nothing, because the state will not be updated when your code will run the `console.log()` ; so don't expect to get debug info with that.

Next, your response is an `object`, not an `array`.
You can do this way : `setData(receiveddata.results)` then you can map() your data.

In your render you should also check if map is not empty like this:

```
  {data && data.map(user => (
    <div key={user.id}>{user.name}, {user.email}</div>
  ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the structure of data comping from your API. Your array is inside `"results"` property. And `"title"` is an object as well. You can find a working example of your code over here [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-grothendieck-cg1j3i?file=/src/App.js). Check the console you will better understand the structure of your response

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you are treating `data` as an array while it contains an object, which is what the **API** returns in this case.

Consider the schema of the data you're getting back from the **API** which is something similar to below. You can see that `results` is the *key* for an array within an object:

```
{ 
  results: [
    {  
      ...
      email: string; 
      id: { 
        name: string; 
        value: string;
      }
      gender: string; 
      name: { 
        title: string;
        first: string; 
        last: string;
      } 
      ...
    } 
}
```

So, to access the `first`, `last` names and `email` properties, you need to call the `map()` method on the `results` array *within* the object which was assigned to `data` as shown below.

Make sure that `data.results` is assigned before trying to access it with `data.results && data.results.map(..)`:

```
{
  data.results && data.results.map(user => (
    <div key={user.id.value}>
      {user.name.first}, {user.name.last}, {user.email}
    </div>)) 
}
```